# Hosting a Dash Interactive App in Django - InvalidConfig `routes_pathname_prefix` needs to start with `/`

Tags: django, url, routes, plotly-dash

I have already build a Dash App that has its callback functions and everything I need. Now I want to host that in a Django app. Ive been trying for three days now but keep getting :

`routes_pathname_prefix` needs to start with `/`

When debugging I notice my url_base_pathname starts with 'https', but I am new to this so I'm very confused.

My App

`app = DjangoDash(name='SimpleExample', )`

Settings

```
PLOTLY_COMPONENTS = [
    'dash_core_components',
    'dash_html_components',
    'dash_table',
    'dash_renderer',
    'dpd_components',
    ]
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
ASGI_APPLICATION = "core.routing.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379), ],
        },
    },
}

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django_plotly_dash.finders.DashAssetFinder',
    'django_plotly_dash.finders.DashComponentFinder',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "home",
    "generate_train_data",
    "preprocess_train_data",
    "django_plotly_dash.apps.DjangoPlotlyDashConfig",
    "channels",
    "channels_redis",

]
```

My HTML extension

```
{% extends 'home.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% load plotly_dash %}
<body>
<div class="{% plotly_class name="SimpleExample" %} card" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    {% plotly_app name="SimpleExample"%}
</div>
</body>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

{{script| safe}}
{% endblock content %}
```

The urls

```
urlpatterns= [
path("", include('preprocess_train_data.urls')),
path("", include('prediction.urls')),
path("django_plotly_dash/", include('django_plotly_dash.urls')),] + static(settings.STATIC_SUFFIX, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

It seems like nomatter what I do it won't work, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see [this](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/359)? It may be some bug that is already fixed. Try to update your software to higher version.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am using dash 2.7.0... Still no clue why this is happening

Comment: I noticed the routes_prefix variable will get set equal to the url_basepath var routes_pathname_prefix 
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/django_plotly_dash/app/simpleexample/'
url_base_pathname 
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/django_plotly_dash/app/simpleexample/'